# Array of times for each day of the week in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have times that I would like to compare to the current time for each day of the week. From what I've come across, it sounds like the best thing to do would be to have an array for each day of the week with the given times I want. For example:

mondayTimes(2:00:00, 5:00:00, 9:00:00, 14:00:00)
tuesdayTimes(3:00:00, 6:00:00, 10:00:00, 15:00:00)

etc...

I want to find out the given day of the week using the current date, and then depending on what day it is, use the array of times for that given day. Then use the current time to find which time is next in the array.

Basically it is like an "alarm clock" that always has set times for every day of the week.

Do I use NSStrings to populate the dates in each array and convert them so I am able to compare them to the current time? What is the best route to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: For comparing times I would use instances of NSDate.  If you need to then display the times you could use the NSDateFormatter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current date, use `NSDate currentDate = [NSDate date];`

Then, to extract the weekday: initialize a `NSCalendar` of your choice, then call `[calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];`, where calendar is your calendar instance.

This produces a number between 1 and 7 (for the Gregorian calendar) where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday. I would then advise you put all of your times in an array of arrays, with the 1 index containing an array of your sundayTimes, 2 containing an array of mondayTimes, ... 7 containing an array of your saturdayTimes.

Then using `[allTimes objectAtIndex weekday]` will return a `NSArray` of your times. All that's left is to compare the times, which I'm sure you can figure out.

Comment: Wouldn't my 0 index contain Sunday, 1 contain Monday, and so on? Also, when I am populating my array times, is there a way to populate arrays with dates or would I just use a string matching the time?

Comment: well, then you would have to do a subtraction to get it to line up with the way iOS does it for the gregorian calendar. It's up to you, but I would think an extra spot in your array for better readability is a good compromise.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Just to match them up. Do I just populate each array within the array with strings? "7:00:00" or is there a better way to do that for collecting times?

Comment: Basically is there a way to compare two strings once I use NSDateFormatter on a date, to find the time difference between the two times?

Comment: I would use the calendar with `dateFromComponents` method to create an `NSDate` of the dates in the subarrays. As for comparisons, assuming you have strings of format `hh:mm:ss`, then you just slice up the string into the 3 components, and compare using that (`if hour1 > hour2` etc.)